# PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15

Tags: php.ini

У клиента на хостинге стоит `PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15`

**Не понимает код вида:**

```
$arr = [];
$site_login = Install::select()[0]["name"]
```

Это пока всё что нашел на данный момент, не известно что в будущем еще может вылезти.

Подскажите есть ли в `php.ini` опции, которые отвечают за подобный синтаксис? Или только поднимать версию php ?

Comment: Обноваить php до 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опций нет, поэтому у вас два варианта: либо исправлять код, либо обновлять php (минимум до 5.4, но лучше, конечно, до 5.6, только она сейчас из 5-ой ветки активно поддерживается).

Сконвертировать массивы в старый синтаксис, например, можно при помощи автоматических инструментов, а вот дереференс результата работы функции уже, скорее всего, только руками. Я рекомендую потратить время не на костылизацию, а на обновление php.

К слову, поддержку версии 5.3 прекратили более полутора лет назад, а апгрейд с 5.3 до 5.6 происходит практически безболезненно.